# FileNotFoundException Jasperreports

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, ireport

1. I am loading an jrxml file in netbeans which is succefully loaded.
   But when I'm deploying it as a jar file it gives the below error:

**Error**

```
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src \Reports\print.jrxml(The system cannot find the path specified)
```

**Code**

```
try
{   
 jasperdesign=JRXmlLoader.load("src/Reports/print.jrxml");
} 
catch(Exception error) 
{
Notify.showMessageDialog(null, ""+error+"", "Error Loading Appointment JasperForm", Notify.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the dir named `src`is in you jar

try getting an InputStream using [ClassLoader's method getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to your packed jrmx file and pass it to the [JRXmlLoader's load](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/xml/JRXmlLoader.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) method that takes an InputStream as argument.

the argument for `getResourceAsStream` should be the full qualified name of the jrxml in your jar. That is, including the package name.

Comment: **InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/Reports/Print.jrxml");**   
      **jasperdesign=JRXmlLoader.load(in);** Is this right?

Comment: the dir named `src`  is not part of the directory/package structure inside your jar file. a jar file is just a zip file. open it with the zip program of your choice an see what's inside it.

Comment: almost, but again, i doubt src is part of your jar content. what is the directory structure of your project ?

Comment: I have opened the JAR file using zip program,The report folder is visible their but the src folder is not visible

Comment: src is not visible because it is not there :) . I guess you find the directory `Reports` and than inside it  `Print.jrxml`, if it is so than just remove the `src/` part from your first comment and it should work. btw it should also work from NetBeans

Comment: I tried removing src/ from my comment and tried but it gives error **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException**

Comment: getResourceAsStream retunrs null if the resource was not found. From the error you are getting now i guess JR came further and is now trying to process the report. do you have some resources that the report should load ? read about the exception you are getting here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html

Comment: I will need some time to find what's going on wrong in this code

Comment: I am pretty sure the reason for the last exception resides in the report `Print.jrxml`. Good luck!